# Client checks if all prefixes are stored correctly in a JSON file. Discord.py

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

### Answer (updated)

New update guys, I chose to remove this because I read that this code, and basically this whole thing I had created, was not good enough and if the bot would get larger, it would cause problems because it would overload the `.JSON` file. So I did this:

**Main File:**

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as file:
        prefixes = json.load(file)

    if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

    else:
        return "/"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)
```

**Prefixes File: (INSIDE A COG)**

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

        with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

So before this "Update" the bot would just load the Default prefix to the `.JSON` file. Now what I have done is that the `Get_Prefix` will check if the guild's ID is on the `.JSON` File, and if in any case is not in there it will use the `/` as a Default prefix. This will help because the code will not have to store every single server to the `.JSON` File which would cause problems in the future if the bot had the chance to get bigger and more well known.

So then in the Prefix File (can be also used in your Main File but you will have to remove the `Self` that I have used.) I removed the code which the bot would have to add the prefix to the `.JSON` file and I only let the part that will remove the Guild's Custom Prefix if it is on the `.JSON` file. That's pretty much it, if you have any more questions I can help you with this just comment in this question!

---

### Question

I'm struggling to find a solution in a large problem I have with my bot. Basically I'm using a `per-server-prefix` code, which I found as a tutorial in the Internet. It's a pretty basic one, I believe that there are more advanced codes than this one but that's not the point at the moment. Before I begin with my problem I want to explain to you how my code works, Basically whenever the Client joins a new server it will save it's ID in a JSON File and it will give it a Default Prefix.

```py
import discord
import json
import asyncio
import os
from discord.ext import commands

class Prefixes(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '/'

        with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

        with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

then if you wish to change the prefix to something else you can use the command `/prefix` and it will change to the new prefix while the client will save the new prefix in the JSON File.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
    async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix=None):

        if prefix == None:

            try:
                x = ""
                pfp = self.client.user.avatar_url
                prefix = discord.Embed(title=x, description=f"My prefix for **{ctx.guild.name}** is `{ctx.prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{ctx.prefix}help`.", color = 0x456383)
                prefix.set_footer(text=f"ChizLanks", icon_url=pfp)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed = prefix)
                return

            except discord.Forbidden:
                return await ctx.channel.send(f"My prefix for **{ctx.guild.name}** is `{ctx.prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{ctx.prefix}help`")
                
        else:
            with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
                prefixes = json.load(f)

            prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

            with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

            await ctx.channel.send(f'Server Prefix has changed to `{prefix}`')
```

That's pretty much the code, I also use some errors for the command but that is not needed at the moment. My problem is that if the client is offline the code is basically not running, that means if the bot gets invited to a new server, the client will not be able to save the prefix to the JSON File and this will cause problems to the server, because when the client will get back online, it will not have any prefix and that means that they will not be able to use any commands.

Now how can that be fixed? I already have an idea of how it will work. I will probably need to use `on_ready` event and that event will search if the servers that the client has joined are in the JSON File it will use them, otherwise it will create a a new prefix (The Default One) and it will save it to the JSON File. That's my idea but I need some help because I do not have any idea if this is even possible. How might this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a default prefix that is recognized by the bot if there is no prefix found for the server. That way, when the very first command is sent in a server, the bot can recognize it even though it wasn't added to the prefix file. Then, when it runs that default prefix, the server could then be registered in the JSON file and everything will be normal from there.

Comment: How would it get stored to the JSON File, after you use the command? I mean the only way I have learned it is `on_guild_join`. If you can somehow explain to me how this worked, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I believe you can set a prefix by running the following when your bot starts running: 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/"')
Then, instead of saying @commands.command() before your methods, you can say @bot.commands() to run your methods. This will allow you to say something like /prefix right off the bat, even if you didn't register it in your JSON file.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: I wrote this already but I deleted because you edited your answer. Basically this will just break my prefix system because I am already using that by the following code:
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)`. This basically get's the prefix from the .JSON File. The problem here is that if I put the code that you told me, the bot will get that as a Prefix and not the prefix in the JSON File. This means that the `per-server-prefix` system won't work at all. Even if put 2 prefixes, the `/` that you said and `get_prefix` the bot will have 2 prefixes and that will be another problem

Comment: A potential workaround would be to check if the guild ID of a message is in your database any time you receive a message. You could use 
`@bot.listen('on_message') 
async def ensure_guild_prefix(message):` 
for this, and do `message.guild.id` to get the guild ID. If it isn't in the prefix database, you could add it here. This probably wouldn't be the most efficient solution, but it would probably get the job done.

Comment: It did took me a while to get it right, but I actually managed to write the command, the right way. I will also edit the answer so other people can get an idea of how this works. Thanks for the Idea mate!